# Sub-setting symmetric matrices along the diagonal

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an 8x8 matrix, e.g. `A=rand(8,8)`. What I need to do is subset all 2x2 matrices along the diagonal. That means that I need to save matrices `A(1:2,1:2)`, `A(3:4,3:4)`, `A(5:6,5:6)`, `A(7:8,7:8)`. To better explain myself, the current version that I am using is the following:

```
 AA = rand(8,8);
 BB = zeros(8,2);
 for i = 1:4
     BB(2*i-1:2*i,:) = AA(2*i-1:2*i,2*i-1:2*i);
 end
```

This works fine for small `AA` matrices and small `AA` submatrices, however as the size grows significantly (it can get up to even 50,000x50,000) using a `for` loop like the one above in not viable. Is there a way to achieve the above without the loop? I've thought of other approaches that could perhaps utilize upper and lower triangular matrices, however even these seem to need a loop at some point. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Will the size of `AA` always be divisible by 2?

Comment: Not necessarily. The size of the matrices that we will need to subset may change in size, but they will always be perfect dividers of the original matrix. E.g., for the current matrix we could also subset all 4x4 matrices along the diagonal (but not 3x3 or 5x5 for example). For a 9x9 matrix, we would subset the 3x3 matrices along the diagonal, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
AA = rand(8,8); % example matrix. Assumed square
n = 2; % submatrix size. Assumed to divide the size of A
mask = repelem(logical(eye(size(AA,1)/n)), n, n);
BB = reshape(permute(reshape(AA(mask), n, n, []), [1 3 2]), [], n);
```

This generates a [logical mask](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) that selects the required elements, and then rearranges them as desired using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).

Comment: LM, that's slick

Comment: @greengrass62 Thanks :-)

Comment: This is amazing! I would have never figured out something so elegant by myself. Thanks a lot LM!!

Comment: @J.Avra Glad you like it

Comment: You're going to hate me. You probably already did anyway. OP's loop code is about 20x faster than this solution on my computer. :)

Comment: @Cris I suspected it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative that doesn't generate a full matrix to select the block diagonals, as in [Luis Mendo' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56194538/7328782) but instead directly generates the indices to these elements. It is likely that this will be faster for very large matrices, as creating the indexing matrix will be expensive in that case.

```matlab
AA = rand(8,8); % example matrix. Assumed square
n = 2; % submatrix size. Assumed to divide the size of A

m=size(AA,1);
bi = (1:n)+(0:m:n*m-1).'; % indices for elements of one block
bi = bi(:);               % turn into column vector
di = 1:n*(m+1):m*m;       % indices for first element of each block
BB = AA(di+bi-1);         % extract the relevant elements
BB = reshape(BB,n,[]).'   % put these elements in the desired order
```

---

### Benchmark

```matlab
AA = rand(5000); % couldn't do 50000x50000 because that's too large!
n = 2;

BB1 = method1(AA,n);
BB2 = method2(AA,n);
BB3 = method3(AA,n);
assert(isequal(BB1,BB2))
assert(isequal(BB1,BB3))

timeit(@()method1(AA,n))
timeit(@()method2(AA,n))
timeit(@()method3(AA,n))

% OP's loop
function BB = method1(AA,n)
m = size(AA,1);
BB = zeros(m,n);
for i = 1:m/n
   BB(n*(i-1)+1:n*i,:) = AA(n*(i-1)+1:n*i,n*(i-1)+1:n*i);
end
end

% Luis' mask matrix
function BB = method2(AA,n)
mask = repelem(logical(eye(size(AA,1)/n)), n, n);
BB = reshape(permute(reshape(AA(mask), n, n, []), [1 3 2]), [], n);
end

% Cris' indices
function BB = method3(AA,n)
m = size(AA,1);
bi = (1:n)+(0:m:n*m-1).';
bi = bi(:);
di = 0:n*(m+1):m*m-1;
BB = reshape(AA(di+bi),n,[]).';
end
```

On my computer, with MATLAB R2017a I get:

- `method1` (OP's loop): 0.0034 s
- `method2` (Luis' mask matrix): 0.0599 s
- `method3` (Cris' indices): 1.5617e-04 s

Note how, for a 5000x5000 array, the method in this answer is ~20x faster than a loop, whereas the loop is ~20 faster than Luis' solution.

For smaller matrices things are slightly different, Luis' method is almost twice as fast as the loop code for a 50x50 matrix (though this method still beats it by ~3x).